# How to convert from decimal to binary invert it with ~ and convert back to decimal

Tags: c#

Not sure if I am in the right direction.
I can't find info about tilde.

```
int n = 5;
int m = ~n;

string numAsString = Convert.ToString(~n, 2);

char[] NumAsChar = numAsString.ToCharArray();

long l = Convert.ToInt64(numAsString, 2);

Console.WriteLine(numAsString);
Console.WriteLine(l);
```

Comment: Documentation of "tilde operator" or rather [bitwise complement operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2bd4x66.aspx). For the rest you have to explain more what is the expected result for example ? Why do you want to convert from/to binary **representation** ? etc.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably looking for a simple answer.

```
int n = 5;
byte[] nbytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(n);
for(int i = 0 ; i < nbytes.Length; i++)
    nbytes[i] = ~nbytes[i];
n = BitConverter.ToInt32(nbytes, 0);
```

edit: you actually can't do ~ on a byte[]. You can either do

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < nbytes.Length; i++)
    nbytes[i] = ~nbytes[i];
```

or just not use a byte array at all.

For clarity's sake, do note that you can just do

```
n = ~n;
```

and skip doing any of the separation. But you specifically asked for the byte conversion.

Comment: I would add a comment to the `nbytes = ~nbytes;` line to make it more clear that that line won't compile.

Comment: Yeah, I'm currently looking up how to use strikethrough here...
Ended up just replacing it. Thanks for the comment :)

Comment: Why not `n = ~n;`? How splitting `n` to bytes and then reassembling them change anything?

Comment: *shrugs* beats me! That's what the asker requested though

Answer (score 0):

Use these 2 methods

```
static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    return bytes;
}

static string GetString(byte[] bytes)
{
    char[] chars = new char[bytes.Length / sizeof(char)];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, chars, 0, bytes.Length);
    return new string(chars);
}
```

And then use them like this

```
byte[] bytes = GetTheBytes(str);
byte[] reversed = bytes.Reverse().ToArray();
var revStr = GetString(reversed)
```

Comment: ~ doesn't reverse the bytes, it inverts them. 0 -> 1 and 1 -> 0

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this.Any suggestions on making it simpler.

```
        int n = 100;
        //Convert decimal to binary
        string numAsString = Convert.ToString(n, 2);

        char[] NumAsChar = numAsString.ToCharArray();

        Console.WriteLine(numAsString);
        //Invert bits 
        for (int i = 0; i < numAsString.Length; i++)
        {
            if (NumAsChar[i] == '0')
            {
                NumAsChar[i] = '1';
            }
            else
            {
                NumAsChar[i] = '0';
            }
        }

        string NewNumAsString = new string(NumAsChar);
        //Convert inverted binary num to decimal
        long l = Convert.ToInt64(NewNumAsString, 2);

        Console.WriteLine(NewNumAsString);
        Console.WriteLine(l);
```